# Typewritting effect ussing React and SSE OpenAI

Tags: reactjs

how could I create a typewriting effect using this library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-typewriter) and sse openai? I still tried to add directly word by word, but the last word will always be displayed

```
const [words, setWords] = useState([]);
while (! done) {
      const { value, done: doneReading } = await reader.read();
      done = doneReading;
      const chunkValue: string = decoder.decode(value);
      if (chunkValue.startsWith('data: ')) {
        const jsonDataString: string = chunkValue.substring(6);
        try {
          const event: any = JSON.parse(jsonDataString);
          if (event.data === "") continue
          console.log(event.data)
          console.log(event.data === "", event.data, event.data === "" ? "Contains empty space" : "No empty space")
          if (event.event !== PING && event.event !== FINISHED_STREAM) {
            console.log(`Message received at ${new Date().toLocaleString()}`, event.data);
            messageCount++;
            answer += parseContent(event.data, messageCount);

            // @ts-ignore
            setWords((prevWords) => [...prevWords, event.data]);

            console.log(words);

            setMessages((prevMessages: IMockStartMessage[]) => {
              const updatedMessages: IMockStartMessage[] = [...prevMessages];

              if (
                  prevMessages.length === 0 ||
                  prevMessages[prevMessages.length - 1].type === "question"
              ) {
                updatedMessages.push({type: "answer", content: answer, bubble: ""});
              } else {
                // Only for streaming
                updatedMessages[updatedMessages.length - 1].content = answer;
                updatedMessages[updatedMessages.length - 1].bubble = "";
              }

              return updatedMessages;
            });
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`Error parsing JSON:, error ${chunkValue}`);
        }
      }
    }
<Typewriter
                    words={words}
                    typeSpeed={7}
                    deleteSpeed={5}
                    delaySpeed={10}
                />
```